# How to get rid of black light on second monitor on ubuntu mate 20.04?

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, hp, hdmi, external-monitor

I am trying to get rid of the black light on my second monitor using Ubuntu mate 20.04.

My station has an AMD Ryzen7 CPU and 2 GPUs:

- Integrated - AMD Radeon Dedicated
- Nvidia GTX 1650 Mobile.

I've installed the NVIDIA drivers and I am currently using the recommended one, however all I can see on my second monitor is a black light. I am able to move windows from different apps on the monitor, I just cannot see them because of the black light. The GPU currently used for render is the AMD one. I am using an HDMI-HDMI connection.

Any help would be really appreciated. TIA :>

Comment: I'm afraid it is not clear what you mean by "black light". Is the screen on or not? In Display settings, is it activated or not? Which screen is connected to which video card?

Comment: The second monitor is activated in display settings. The gpu used for rendering is the nvidia one. The Black light I'm not sure I would go about explaining it but it looks like that: https://images.app.goo.gl/HW5D65R6XTZUdzJy9

Comment: Hm, not sure from the pictures what that effect is, but it sounds like your monitor is on and working, but does not produce an image, right? Does the monitor work when you connect it alone? Does it work on either graphics card? Does the other monitor work on either graphics card? A bit of basic troubleshooting might be needed...

Comment: I had to perform a clean reinstall of the OS and I eventually managed to get it working properly using the nvidia-driver-455. The problem is that I had my external monitor attached to my laptop while I  was performing the install and now it seems I cannot use the ubuntu OS if I dont have my external monitor hooked up through my hdmi. Any hints on that?